# Has my computer been hacked

Tags: macos, security

I'm trying to find out if someone has hacked my computer. In case I get the following message in my Terminal window: "Last login: Tue Sep 30 02:02:18 on console" does that mean a person has logged in, or could it be an automatic programme running?

Comment: If your computer were hacked, you would probably have seen an ip address instead of `console`. I don't know what `console` means though, mine shows `TTY##` instead

Answer (score 2):

Popmoi, the last login on console is exactly that: Somebody (likely you) logged into a bash session on your computer at 2:02:18 on Sep 30. Generally, 'console' is shown for the first shell login and then ttys000 would be the next. I see this every login/reboot for my Terminal group, which opens two bash sessions in different tabs.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I was asleep at 2:02:18. That said, I also checked my Console, but had no 'LidOpen' reported for that time. I have five ttys000 messages from around 13h today. My computer is a Macbook. I really want to find out if someone hacked my computer, but also need to be 100% sure.

Comment: I'd be curious to see your `uptime` (type that command into a bash prompt and see what it says. Is it possible that your system rebooted around that time? System Update or some such?

Comment: Sorry, not sure to know how to get my uptime, do I type it into the Terminal window?

Comment: Yep. That's how you'd do it. :)

Comment: I typed it into the Terminal window and got the following message: up 11:56, 2 users, load averages: 1.29 1.30 1.25

Comment: And I'm guessing that 12 hours ago was around 2 a.m., yes?

Comment: Exactly, that was 12 hours ago!

Comment: Okay, so the next step is to figure out what your computer was doing 12 hours ago that caused it to restart. I'm guessing Software Updates. You can investigate that further by looking at the system logs in the Console app.

Comment: Here's a sample of the system log around that time:

Comment: 30/09/14 02:01:36,761 reboot[19174]: SHUTDOWN_TIME: 1412035296 760584
30/09/14 02:01:36,860 WindowServer[19083]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 35331
30/09/14 02:01:36,860 WindowServer[19083]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 35331
30/09/14 02:01:36,861 WindowServer[19083]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 35331
30/09/14 02:02:13,000 syslogd[17]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.authd" claims selected messages.
30/09/14 02:02:13,000 syslogd[17]: Configuration Notice:
30/09/14 02:02:13,000 syslogd[17]: Configuration Notice:

Comment: ASL Module "com.apple.MessageTracer" claims selected messages.
30/09/14 02:02:13,000 syslogd[17]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.performance" claims selected messages.
30/09/14 02:02:13,000 syslogd[17]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
30/09/14 02:02:13,000 syslogd[17]: Configuration Notice:
30/09/14 02:02:13,000 kernel[0]: "vm_compressor_mode" is 4
30/09/14 02:02:13,000 kernel[0]: standard timeslicing quantum is 10000 us

Comment: Okay, we know that the system rebooted. What you want to know is what it was doing BEFORE it rebooted. :)

Comment: right! :-) This is what happened just before: 30/09/14 02:00:45,570 mdworker32[19062]: CGSGetSpaceManagementMode: No connection with id 0x       0
30/09/14 02:00:53,522 com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Killing auth hosts
30/09/14 02:00:53,522 com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Session 100069 destroyed
30/09/14 02:00:53,974 mds[66]: (Normal) ImportServer: Preparing for software update

Comment: 30/09/14 02:01:02,035 com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Killing auth hosts
30/09/14 02:01:02,035 com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Session 100068 destroyed
30/09/14 02:01:06,435 coreservicesd[36]: Posted system configuration change notification
30/09/14 02:01:12,336 com.apple.usbmuxd[49]: stopping.
30/09/14 02:01:12,406 com.apple.usbmuxd[19113]: usbmuxd-344 on Jul 29 2014 at 13:52:57, running 64 bit
30/09/14 02:01:35,112 mds[66]: (Normal) ImportServer: Software update complete
30/09/14 02:01:36,760 reboot[19174]: rebooted by _atsserver

Comment: And there's your answer: Software update complete 30/09/14 02:01:36,760 reboot --- Good job!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I REALLY appreciate it, and so happy that I did not have time to start accusing anyone of hacking into my computer! ps. I saw that you're based in Tokyo, I worked there for some months back in 1989. Crazy but great city!